# How to add multiple labels at different "Top" position in UserForm using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm trying to create a UserForm using VBA where I have a MultiPage with 5 pages and need to insert 5 items in each of the Page. The MultiPage works fine and inserting items as labels also work, but I cannot adjust the position from the top.

Following is the code that loops through the page and inserts items. I tried to update the Top position by some calculation such that when it loops, it dynamically updates the value. It starts with 0 and then adds the size of the label
`itemTopPosition = 0 itemTopPosition = itemTopPostion + itemLbl.Height`

When I rant the test, the first pass it updates the value but it doesn't set the value after the first pass in the loop. Why?

```
'rngTable rows have different count than rngTable.Count if multiple columns are selected
    For i = 1 To rngTable.Rows.Count
        itemTopPosition = 0
        'get leader role id
        activeLeaderRoleId = rngTable.Item(i, 1).Value
        
        'MsgBox ("Adding pages")
        
        If (i <= pageCount) = True Then
            multiPage.Pages(i - 1).Caption = rngTable.Item(i, 2).Value
        Else
            multiPage.Pages.Add
            Me.DriverTabs.Pages(i - 1).Name = "Page" & i
            Me.DriverTabs.Pages(i - 1).Caption = rngTable.Item(i, 2).Value
            
        End If
        
        'Loop through item table to add items to the multipage page
        For j = 1 To itemTable.Rows.Count
            
            'MsgBox ("Item Label: " & i & " " & j)
            
            'MsgBox ("Item position: " & itemTopPosition)
            
            If itemTable.Item(j, 2).Value = activeLeaderRoleId And itemTable.Item(j, 3) = jobGrade Then
                'MsgBox ("adding item")
                lblName = "lr" & i & "Item" & j
                
                Set itemLbl = multiPage.Pages(i - 1).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", lblName)
                
                
                MsgBox ("Item: " & j & "\n Postion: " & itemTopPosition)
                With itemLbl
                        .Caption = itemTable.Item(j, 4).Value
                        .Left = 6
                        .Width = 350
                        .Height = 30
                        .Top = itemTopPosition
                End With
                MsgBox ("Updateing position")
                itemTopPosition = itemTopPostion + itemLbl.Height  '<---------- (this is my problem)
                MsgBox ("Position: " & itemTopPosition)
                MsgBox ("Postion updated")
            End If
        
        Next j 'End item table range
    Next i 'End leader role table range
```

Comment: There's a typo in line "itemTopPosition = itemTopPostion + ...". Put Option Explicit at the top of your module, and Debug/Compile.

Comment: Always use Option Explicit.  This would have shown you the error very quickly.

Comment: Is the condition `If itemTable.Item(j, 2).Value = activeLeaderRoleId And itemTable.Item(j, 3) = jobGrade Then` True? Does your code create labels? Do you see all the labels you expect to be created?

Comment: Yes, it does create the label, but it adds all 5 on top of each other

Comment: @Excelosaurus and @Brian M Stafford, that was really. That was it. it was because of the typo and `Option Explicit` showed it.